# How to use relative addressing in html

Tags: html, relative-path

I'm trying to use relative addressing instead of absolute in a project for school and can't figure out what i'm doing wrong.On my school's server I have everything listed under project then all the content is in my two sub directories of webpages and images.I tried using "../picture.jpg" but it didn't work. What am I doing wrong .project is just username/project/images or webpages and heres the code im trying "/project/webpages/home.html"

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. You need to provide more detail, perhaps what the project structure is like, what technologies you're using, how is it deployed, etc. Some code would be really helpful. Please, have  a look at [How-to-ask guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and  [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please, put that in your question, not a comment.

Comment: You have an image inside an image folder, but the path you have given would turn into `project/webpages/picture.jpg` since you are currently in the webpages folder and `../` only goes up one directory you might want `../../images/picture.jpg`